# Uniform Continuity on an Open Interval

Tags: real-analysis

My teacher was saying that it is possible to extend $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is uniformly continuous to $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous.
How is that done?

Comment: This is a nice little exercise.  There really is only one extension that you could do.  Notice that $[a,b]$ is closed.  What do you know about closed sets?

Comment: Sequentially Compact?

Comment: Right, so take a sequence $x_n \rightarrow b$.  Then define your "function" $F$ to be $F(b) = \lim f(x_n)$ and $F(x) = f$ for $x \not= b$ (similar for left end point).  So, it's now your job to show this is well defined ($F$ actually is a function) and is continuous.

Comment: So is testing well defined mean that the value will be the same for any sequence that converges to b?

Comment: @PaulMalinowski: You are on right track. First you need to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_{n})$ exists and then if $y_{n} \to b$ is another sequence then $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(y_{n})$. Showing continuity of $F(x)$ at $x = b$ should not be a major issue.

Comment: I understand now, thanks everyone!